# Output redirection of real-time stdout doesn't work after piping it into uniq or awk

Tags: bash, uniq, fswatch

I'm trying to run

```
fswatch -tr /home/*/*/public_html | grep --line-buffered -E ".php|.xml" | awk '!seen[$0]++' >> log.txt
```

or equivalently (by using `uniq`):

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 fswatch -tr /home/*/*/public_html | grep --line-buffered -E ".php|.xml" | uniq >> log.txt
```

So that I don't get duplicate rows. It works just fine in the terminal, with standard output, however when I'm trying to write that output to `log.txt`, the file is blank (or no new rows are inserted if using `>>`).

`fswatch` is a command that "monitors" changes to the filesystem in real time, and it generates a lot of duplicate events and `uniq` seems to address that just fine.

Any ideas why the output redirection doesn't work?

Comment: try removing `--line-buffered`

Comment: @Fravadona that unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Even though `grep` is line buffered, unless you have an `awk` that has that same option its output will be fully buffered.  Similarly for `uniq`.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` and `uniq` are going to buffer their output when writing to a regular file.  You can get unbuffered behavior with `perl`:

```
... | perl -ne '$|=1; print unless ${$_}++'
```

That is the `perl` equivalent of `awk '!seen[$0]++'`, but setting `$|` non-zero makes the output unbuffered.  To be more correct you should probably write `BEGIN{$|=1}` so you're not making the assignment on every line of input, but it's not really necessary.

Comment: You're right, it's due to the buffering of the text processing command. BTW, keeping almost all the lines in memory isn't a good idea

Comment: *BTW, keeping almost all the lines in memory isn't a good idea* It would be trivial to replace `${$_}++` with something like `${md5($_)}` which is a fraction of the footprint...

Comment: @dawg I didn't think of using a hash, that would save a lot of RAM. The main problem remains though: the consumption is infinite because the lines are all timestamped

Comment: This is awesome. Just one thing, can you make it so that it behaves more like `uniq` in the sense that *only* adjacent lines are matched for uniqueness? This would minimize RAM requirements to only the last line's size. I.e. don't output a line if it's just like the last line.

Comment: @Unknown.  That's a fairly trivial change: `perl -ne '$|=1; print unless $_ eq $prev; $prev=$_`

Answer (score 0):

formatting didn't look right in comment, so simply re-pasting it for clarity :

```
mawk '!__[$_]--{ print; fflush() }'
```